# $_POST array processing with php using a var in the $_POST[]

Tags: php, post

I am making a form that displays customers and the associated accounts to that customer.
for example 
customer John has 3 accounts

```
account_Id 1 account_type hardware
account_Id 4 account_type service
account_Id 6 account_type software
```

The form is created by selecting all the account information from the database and then

```
$acc_i=0;
foreach($account as $acc){
?>
    <tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="account_count" value="<?php echo $acc_i; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $acc_i; ?>_cust_account_id" value="<?php echo $acc['Id'];?>" />
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
<?php
$acc_i++;
}
```

This gives me a $_POST array with

```
account_count => 1
0_cust_account_id => 1
1_cust_account_id => 4
1_cust_account_id => 6
```

Is it possible to access the values using something like

```
for($i=0;$i<=$_POST['account_count'];$i++){ echo $_POST[$i _cust_account_id];}
```

Comment: `Is it possible to access the values using something like...` Well, thats easy to find out, just try it!

Comment: You could also try using arrayish `<input name="whatever[123]">` input field names instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with lists of data to send in a post request consider using arrays for example if you want to send a list of ids you could do a form like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="CustomerId[]" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="CustomerId[]" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="CustomerId[]" value="3" />
```

and then when thats submitted those values can be accessed by

```
$_POST['CustomerId'] == array(1, 2, 3)

count($_POST['CustomerId']) == Number of accounts?
```

Comment: thank you. I am not a real programmer and multiple dimension arrays always get me in trouble. I can initiate the array but then accessing the data with php is always a nightmare.
Are there performance gains in sending the data in an array ?

Comment: You can always use the handy print_r($_POST); to see what has been sent from the form. But compared with your other method I would say this way is cleaner and more understandable. Don't worry about performance

Answer (score -1):

while asking the question I found a solution that will work
instead of trying

```
$_POST['.$i.'_cust_account_id];
```

I use this

```
$string=$i.'_cust_account_id';
$_POST[$string]
```

If you know how to avoid using an extra variable, please post it.

Comment: does not work as it is part of a string
$accountid = $i.'_cust_account_id';
$accounttypeid = $i.'_account_type_id';
$table02="account";
$queryaccount="UPDATE $table02 SET $table02.AccountTypeId = $_POST[$accounttypeid] WHERE $table02.Id = $_POST[$accountid];";